# Accessing hadoop from remote machine

Tags: java, hadoop

I have hadoop set up (pseudo distributed) on a server VM and I'm trying
to use the Java API to access the HDFS.

The fs.default.name on my server is `hdfs://0.0.0.0:9000` (as with `localhost:9000` it wouldn't accept requests from remote sites).

I can connect to the server on port 9000

```
$ telnet srv-lab 9000
Trying 1*0.*.30.95...
Connected to srv-lab
Escape character is '^]'.
^C
```

which indicates to me that connection should work fine. The Java code I'm using is:

```
try {
        Path pt = new Path(
                "hdfs://srv-lab:9000/test.txt");
        Configuration conf = new Configuration();
        conf.set("fs.default.name", "hdfs://srv-lab:9000");
        FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(conf);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                fs.open(pt)));
        String line;
        line = br.readLine();
        while (line != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
            line = br.readLine();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

but what I get is:

```
java.net.ConnectException: Call From clt-lab/1*0.*.2*2.205 to srv-lab:9000 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused; For more details see:  http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/ConnectionRefused
```

Thus, any hints on why the connection is refused even though connecting through telnet works fine?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35038835/5678086

Comment: How are you trying to run the code. Is it from within the VM or from the host machine?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your hdfs entry is wrong. fs.default.name has to be set as `hdfs://srv-lab:9000`. Set this and restart your cluster. that will fix the issue

Comment: I've already tried that. I've also tried: localhost:9000, *:9000, 0.0.0.0:9000, <ip>:9000 but none of those work. Yet, connecting with telnet works.

Comment: I mean the fs.default.name in your namenode (core-site.xml) has to be set with `hdfs://srv-lab:9000`

Comment: That's what I meant. But I think I might have had some resolution problems when I tried that. It works now. Thank you :).